# how to remove root login from login screen

Tags: login, root

I have enabled root to login from screen. I want disable it keep normal and guest user on login screen only because even if I login with normal user for shutting down my machine I have to login with root which was not a problem before enabling root login from screen

Answer (score 2):

#### In GDM

Edit `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` file and remove/comment out `AllowRoot=true`.

#### In KDM

Edit `/etc/kde4/kdm/kdmrc` file and change `AllowRootLogin=true` for `AllowRootLogin=false`.

#### In LightDM

This procedure disables the "Other" menu, so you can type the username `root` and login. You must edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and add `greeter-show-manual-login=false`. Then reboot.

To disable root login just type:

```
sudo passwd -dl root
```